# Google Maps Close Street View (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I currently have a Google Maps on my website, and using links to move to different markers that as been placed on it. The markers and the links works perfectly but if the map is in street view - it does nothing the street view remains (but in the background the map does actual fact move, you just have to close the street view to see it).

So my issue is that how could i close the street view. Such as

```
if StreetView Status == True
Close street view

map.setZoom(18);
map.setCenter(lat, lng);
```

Below is the code that when clicking on the link moves the map, to the different markers.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.pan-to-marker', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var lat = $(this).data('marker-lat');
        var lng = $(this).data('marker-lng');
        map.setZoom(18);
        map.setCenter(lat, lng);
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close a streetView set the `visible`-property to `false`

```
map.getStreetView().setVisible(false);
```